# Using transform.position on an instantiated prefab in an array one by one

Tags: unity, 2d, movement

So I've been trying to make an already instantiated prefab to fall one by one in my scene. First they instantiate hidden in the camera and that works so far. But when I apply transform.position on them they don't seem to move. Here's the code

```
   public GameObject[] enemySpawn;




void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemySpawn.Length; i++)
    {
        Instantiate<GameObject>(enemySpawn[i], new Vector2(-4,6),Quaternion.identity);

    }



    StartCoroutine(spawnBlades());
}


void Update()
{

}
IEnumerator spawnBlades() { 
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++ )
        enemySpawn[i].transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3), 6);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

}
```

Comment: So you have `n` different prefabs to spawn? If not, just use a single reference to your prefab and keep the instances. Additionally, you should keep the instances typed (e.g. `Foo[] _instances`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i got it. You have to assign it to another gameobject array like so

```
public GameObject[] enemySpawn;
public GameObject[] enemy;
for (int i = 0; i < enemySpawn.Length; i++)
{
   enemy[i] = Instantiate<GameObject>(enemySpawn[i], new Vector2(-4,6),Quaternion.identity);

}
```